# Como instalar azure swa cli en servidor sin salida a internet?

Tags: npm, azure

hola quiero instalar @azure/static-web-apps-cli con el comando `npm install -g @azure/static-web-apps-cli` Tengo instalado el node.js la ultima versión y el nmp ultima versión. La maquina donde la quiero instalar no tiene internet. ¿Cómo puedo instalarlo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si no tiene acceso a Internet en la máquina donde desea instalar @azure/static-web-apps-cli, deberá descargar manualmente el paquete y sus dependencias en una máquina con conexión a Internet y luego transferirlos a la máquina de destino.

Estos son los pasos:

1. Descargue el paquete @azure/static-web-apps-cli y sus dependencias a través del comando npm pack en una máquina con conexión a Internet. Esto creará un archivo en el directorio actual con el nombre @azure/static-web-apps-cli-.tgz (donde  es la versión del paquete). Ejecute el siguiente comando en la terminal:

   npm pack @azure/static-web-apps-cli
2. Copie el archivo @azure/static-web-apps-cli-.tgz a la máquina de destino utilizando una unidad flash USB, un servidor de archivos o cualquier otro medio.
3. En la máquina de destino, navegue hasta el directorio donde se encuentra el archivo @azure/static-web-apps-cli-.tgz.
4. Instale el paquete @azure/static-web-apps-cli utilizando el archivo descargado a través del siguiente comando:

   npm install -g ./@azure/static-web-apps-cli-.tgz

Nota: Asegúrese de incluir el prefijo ./ en el archivo para indicar que se encuentra en el directorio actual.

5. Una vez que se complete la instalación, verifique si la instalación fue exitosa ejecutando el siguiente comando:

   swa --version

Si el comando devuelve la versión de @azure/static-web-apps-cli, entonces la instalación se realizó correctamente.
Con estos pasos, debería poder instalar @azure/static-web-apps-cli en su máquina sin conexión a Internet.

Para instalar @azure/static-web-apps-cli en su máquina, debe tener instalado Node.js y npm. Asegúrese de tener la versión más reciente de Node.js y npm en su sistema.

Si tampoco tienes el Visual Studio instalado, es posible que debas instalar las herramientas de compilación de C++ de Microsoft para Windows. Esto se debe a que algunas dependencias de @azure/static-web-apps-cli requieren estas herramientas de compilación.

Para instalar las herramientas de compilación de C++ de Microsoft. Estos son los pasos:

Descargue las herramientas de compilación de C++ de Microsoft para Windows desde el siguiente enlace:

https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/es/visual-cpp-build-tools/

Ejecute el archivo de instalación y siga las instrucciones en pantalla para instalar las herramientas de compilación de C++ de Microsoft en su sistema.

Una vez que se complete la instalación ya se puede instalar  @azure/static-web-apps-cli

En mi caso también tuve que instalar Python, puedes hacerlo descargando este archivo:
https://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.7.14/python-2.7.14.amd64.msi